# ¿Significa algo "chimborazo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, topónimos, aumentativos

En varias televisiones autonómicas españolas se va a estrenar un programa llamado "Objetivo Chimborazo". La palabra me recuerda a otras expresiones locales de mi región, como *[bastinazo](https://cadizpedia.wikanda.es/wiki/Bastinazo)*, ya que parece el aumentativo de algo. En la web sólo encuentro referencias al [volcán Chimborazo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volc%C3%A1n_Chimborazo), la montaña más alta de Ecuador y el punto más alejado del centro de la Tierra.

Así pues, pregunta sencilla: ¿es "chimborazo" una palabra que se use en algún país como el aumentativo de algo? ¿Tiene algún significado aparte de ser un topónimo?

Comment: El nombre del programa hace referencia al volcán; es un reality de aventura en la zona del Chimborazo. Si la palabra significa algo más en algún otro sitio, ya no lo sé.

Comment: @Gorpik esa es en realidad la pregunta. Cuando vi que "chimborazo" era el nombre del volcán entendí el título del programa. Ahora se trata de ver si además es alguna palabra de uso local.

Comment: Ah, entonces te he entendido mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que el que la palabra parezca un aumentativo no es más que una coincidencia. La palabra viene del topónimo original en quechua ***[Chimpurasu](https://qu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimpurasu)***. Según la Wikipedia en inglés, hay varias teorías sobre la [etimología de la palabra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimborazo#Etymology), pero parecen coincidir en que la última parte, "razu", significa *hielo* o *nieve*. Así pues, "Chimborazo" no sería más que una castellanización del topónimo original, y no tiene ningún significado añadido.